# Is it possible/advisable to run Rails 6 without webpack(er)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, rails-sprockets

I am starting a new Rails 6 application. If I understood correctly, Webpack(er) (`gem webpacker`) has replaced Sprockets as the new standard for including/minifying JS ([source](https://blog.capsens.eu/how-to-write-javascript-in-rails-6-webpacker-yarn-and-sprockets-cdf990387463)).
Furthermore, Rails 6 now both requires [Node.js and Yarn](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project-installing-rails).

Am I correct in assuming that the Node.js and Yarn dependencies are only due to the inclusion of Webpack, or do other components of Rails 6 also need them?

Are there any possible drawbacks in removing Webpack and Node and Yarn from the Rails 6 app and continuing to use the Rails Asset Pipeline (apart from missing Webpack features)?

Comment: Sprockets still relies on Node.js (or another JS runtime) to do stuff like CSS and JS compression. "Are there any additional drawbacks?". Well you're painting yourself into a corner as most gem packages of frontend stuff will cease to be maintained/updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For CSS and JS compression it's possible to include a JS runtime like `mini_racer` or `therubyracer` (as was the case with Rails 5). Good point about the gem packages!

Comment: The maintainence of sprockets itself is also a concern, I haven't heard that much about it but will it continue to be maintained and will it be compatible with future versions of Rails?

Comment: I know that DHH sees them coexisting but Webpacker can easily do CSS/SCSS and images which is really what Sprockets would still be used for and I can see why you would want to streamline and make it less confusing especially for beginners by just having a single pipeline.

Comment: That is exactly the point! I was hoping to make it easier/less complex for our students, as they would also not have to install node.js and yarn.

Comment: There is a huge advantage for students in learning Yarn and installing Node though as a front-end package manager is really a fact of life in 2020. Node is also available as a point and click installer on most platforms and can be easier to setup then for example Rhino or V8 that therubyracer uses. The main issue really with webpacker in Rails 6 is that the documentation is dismal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can drop gems from Gemfile, delete the created node_modules folder and package.json file.

After that run bundle to clean up the Gemfile.lock and start code the old way with normal views and templates. Mention, that you will have to add js engine like Google V8.

In fact webpacker and node are not required to run a rails 6 application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried it out and Rails 6 seems to use node out of the box solly for JS compression, the old asset pipeline can still be used. I've opened a rails issue with some more details: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40438

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to run Rails 6 without the `webpacker` gem, Node.js and Yarn (see [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35484#issuecomment-632990134)).

However, the `--skip-webpack-install` option of `Rails new` still includes the `webpacker`gem in the Gemfile and sets up the resulting project with webpacker configuration (only `rails webpacker:install` is not run).

If the Rails Asset Pipeline using Sprockets is to be used, the `--skip-javascript` option [is recommended](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35484#issuecomment-469798114) and manual changes are necessary, in particular:

- Add `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` to `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
- Create `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` (contents, e.g. [here](https://github.com/chrisma/rails6-github-actions/blob/main/default/app/assets/javascripts/application.js))
- Add `//= link_directory ../javascripts .js` to `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Answer (score 1):

It's in fact possible to run Rails 6 and higher with gem 'sprockets', '~> 4', gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie' and gem 'sassc-rails' for css and already migrate to gem "importmap-rails" for the javascript. I am updating my apps from 5.2. to 7.1. and it is much less work intensive (if you want to do it version by version) than introducing webpacker and then getting rid of it again for Rails 7. gem sassc-rails has not been maintained since 2019, so I will move forward to Rails 7.1. quickly and then use dartsass-sprockets instead.